# Log any action made by users in sfDoctrineGuard

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I need to log any action made by users in sfDoctrineGuard plugin. Basically I'll need to log:

```
module/action
date
IP from where users are accessing the application
```

Any plugin? Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be probably the plugin you need, [sfDoctrineGuardLoginHistoryPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardLoginHistoryPlugin) and allows to extend the information that you save.

Check for more plugins [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/).

Take a look at the code of the plugin, you just need to change the following file: `PluginUserLoginHistoryTable.class.php`

Add in the function `writeLoginHistory` and `createHistoryEntry` the information you want:

```
writeLoginHistory(sfEvent $event) {
//... same code than in the plugin
//lets save module and action
  if (!isset($request) )
  {
    $sActionName = sfContext::getInstance()->getActionName();
    $sModuleName = sfContext::getInstance()->getModuleName();
  }
  else
  {
    if (isset($request["module"]))
    {
      $sActionName = $request["action"];
      $sModuleName = $request["module"];
    }
  }

  //get values from the http bar URL
  if (!isset($sModuleName))
  {
    $sFullURL = sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentInternalUri();
    ///... strip action and module name from the above URL
  }
}
```

Remember to pass those values to createHistoryEntry function and also to update that function with more input values to be saved.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, I read the docs but can you wrote a example in how to save `module/action`? I mean where or better how do I get this part

Comment: Edited above post to save action and module, check plugin info for more changes.